# Incorrect syntax near @indexName. Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

This seems like a strange behaviour, but the following code is throwing an error:

```cs
public async Task RebuildIndex(string tableName, string indexName)
{
    await _dbConnection.ExecuteAsync($@"
        alter index @indexName on @tableName rebuild;", 
    new
    {
        indexName = indexName,
        tableName = tableName
    });
}
```

Error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "@indexName".
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImplAsync(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Object param) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 678
   at Railways.DbManager.Repositories.DbmIndexDefragmentationRepository.RebuildIndex(String tableName, String indexName) in C:\Railways\asu-itk-core\Railways\Railways.DbManager.Repositories\DbmIndexDefragmentationRepository.cs:line 48
   at Railways.DBManager.Services.IndexDefragmentationService.DefragIndexes() in C:\Railways\asu-itk-core\Railways\Railways.DBManager.Services\IndexDefragmentationService.cs:line 41
ClientConnectionId:7db4e7f6-e01d-4671-9fe3-e22dcb388cd4
Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
```

What can be wrong here?

I am just passing the parameter and this should work.

Maybe I am missing something? Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to parameterize target object names used in SQL statements, i.e. table names and index names can't be parameterized. This isn't just a Dapper restriction - e.g. ADO.Net and `sp_executesql` similarly can't parameterize tables. (speculatively, parameterization protects not just against SQL injection attacks, but also improves execution plan caching based on exact data types - plan caching is obviously not possible if the target table is dynamic).

In your case, you will need to do your own SQL injection checking (if needed - it would be highly unusual for index names and table names to come from an untrusted user), and then just substitute the name into the SQL statement, e.g. via [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) or `String.Format`.

If you *really* accept table or index names from untrusted users and need to guard against SQL injection attacks, you can use [Aaron Betrand's advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212816/5489) and first check for the existence of the table in `sys.tables` and the index in `sys.indexes` before executing the SQL statement.

**Edit**

The reason why you can parameterize the table name in queries against `system` tables like `sys.tables` and `DMVs` like `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` is because here, the name of the table or other object is a value in a column. But similarly, you won't be able to parameterize the name of the system table or DMV itself.

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)

Comment: Could you please check related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55523500/6812826 , somehow I am able to pass table name into sql query.

Comment: Yes but in that case the table name or dB id is the value stored in a column of a row in a (constant) system table, so parameterization is ok. Changing the target table entirely in a query is a different kettle of fish.